# Add External DLL to WIX project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wix, windows-installer, wix3

I'm trying to build an install with Wix in VS 2012, but I am unable to add "external" references

i have my project FirmwareUpload which is the thing I want to install with References to our company's framework. And FirmwareUploadSetup which is my installer project. I Added references in this project to my other project and create the XML :

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="MainEXE">
    <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
    <File Source="$(var.FirmwareUpload.TargetPath)">
      <Shortcut Id="startmenuFWU10" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Firmware Upload 1.0"
                WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Advertise="yes" />
      <Shortcut Id="desktopFWU10" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="Firmware Upload 1.0"
                WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Advertise="yes" />
    </File>

  </Component>
  <Component Id="AstuFMS">
    <File Source="$(var.Astus.FMS.TargetPath)" Name="Astus.FMS.dll" ShortName="AF" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="AstusServerBusinessLogic">
    <File Source="$(var.Astus.Server.BusinessLogic.TargetPath)" Name="Astus.Server.BusinessLogic.dll"
          ShortName="ASBL" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ETL">
    <File Source="$(var.ETLElectronique.TargetPath)" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ETLBusiness">
    <File Source="$(var.ETLElectronique.Business.TargetPath)" Name="ETLElectronique.Business.dll" ShortName="EB" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ETLCommon">
    <File Source="$(var.ETLElectronique.Common.TargetPath)" Name="ETLElectronique.Common.dll" ShortName="EC" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ETLData">
    <File Source="$(var.ETLElectronique.Data.TargetPath)" Name="ETLElectronique.Data.dll" ShortName="ED" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ETLNet">
    <File Source="$(var.ETLElectronique.Net.TargetPath)" Name="ETLElectronique.Net.dll" ShortName="EN" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ETLWindows">
    <File Source="$(var.ETLElectronique.Windows.TargetPath)" Name="ETLElectronique.Windows.dll" ShortName="EW" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

this works !! when i execute the installer I get these files in my directory. But there are other files required for the software to run (Example: log4net.dll)

When I compile my "FirmwareUpload" project I get the log4net.dll (and many others). So I need these DLL in my install for the program to run once installed.

Worked by doing :

```
 <ComponentGroup Id="DocumentationComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Source="C:\fms\hotfix\v42x\V6\Utilitaire\FirmwareUpload\FirmwareUpload\bin\Debug">
      <Component Id="log4net">
        <File Name="log4net.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Astus.Device.Configuration">
        <File Name="Astus.Device.Configuration.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Astus.Device">
        <File Name="Astus.Device.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common">
        <File Name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data">
        <File Name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling">
        <File Name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder">
        <File Name="Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.dll" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
```

But is there a less "hardcoded" way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `heat` (the "Harvest Tool") to scan a folder and generate the xml required to include files in that folder.

See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm

Comment: I did not learn to WIX with command line, is there a similar way to achieve this with the XML ?

Comment: No, the xml has to list out all files explicitly (as far as I'm aware).  Heat is a simple tool you can add as a pre-build step to generate the xml.

Comment: Aright, i'll read more on command line tool, I tough command line was a kind of "another tool" to generate the MSI

Comment: @PLAudet You could use a preprocessor pragma that calls heat, reads the output and writes it to your wxs file.